# C# Regex for a word possibly surrounded by quotes

Tags: c#, regex

For a C# program I'm writing, I'm using regular expressions to look for a specific pattern and this pattern may or may not be surrounded by parentheses, but, if it is, I want to include them in the match.

So for example, say my pattern was just the word `"hello"`, I created this regex:

```
"\(?hello\)?"
```

But that doesn't take into account that the word must have BOTH opening and closing parentheses in order to qualify as a match.
So, for example, if my search string was:

```
hello, (hello), (hello, my name is bob), (bob said hello)
```

What I would want would be to have the following 4 matches - `hello`, `(hello)` `hello`, `hello`

Specifically, the second match includes the parentheses, but **the 3rd and 4th matches do not include any parentheses** since they are not at the beginning AND the ending of the "hello".

What kind of regex could I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use [an alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match `\(hello\)` or `hello`:

```
\(hello\)|hello
```

Since regular expressions are inherently greedy, `(hello)` will be match before `hello` which means that all four of the instances would be matched.

Comment: Oh, DUH!!! - That is a simple and efficient solution! - I went substantially crazier in what I came up with. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos Your solution is still pretty clever, and it would probably be more useful in certain cases where you don't want to repeat the string "hello" twice (assuming it is something more complex) 1+

Comment: Thanks, Josh, but in this case, I kind of feel your solution leans towards simplicity and a "duh, could have had a V8" feeling... I actually already put yours into my solution and it works a charm! - Just waiting out the 10 minutes to mark it as the solution.
THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

Before anyone else spends too much time on this, I did find an answer (but if you have a better way, please do share!!!)

After some research, my final pattern has become:

```
(\()?hello(?(1)\))
```

That uses an optional capturing group and [conditional backreferencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

Again, if anyone has a nicer solution, please do share, but, otherwise, hope this manages to help someone else in the future!